# PHP get rid of all Aces after shuffled

Tags: php, arrays

What is the algorithm to get rid all the Aces after shuffled of 52 cards on the deck? where Aces are not allowed in the output result.

```
<?php
function pc_array_shuffle($array) {
    $i = count($array);

    while(--$i) {
        $j = mt_rand(0, $i);

        if ($i != $j) {
            // swap elements
            $tmp = $array[$j];
            $array[$j] = $array[$i]; 
            $array[$i] = $tmp;
        }
    }

    return $array;
}

$suits = array('Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades');
$cards = array('Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King');

$deck = pc_array_shuffle(range(1, 52));


$n=1;
while(($draw = array_pop($deck)) != NULL) {

    echo $n.') '.$cards[$draw / 4] . ' of ' . $suits[$draw % 4] . '<br />';
    $n++;
}
?>
```

http://codepad.org/yUrrT2m1

Comment: Why not eliminate the aces ___before___ shuffling?

Comment: @MarkBaker: A card player would probably say that would affect the validity of the shuffle. Still, going by the OP's user name that's probably not an issue. ;)

Comment: Like this? http://codepad.org/JyDeOR7d

Comment: When running this code I get warning: `Notice: Undefined offset: 13 in ... on line 28`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$suits = array('Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades');
$cards = array('Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King');
$deck = array();
$no_aces = array();

// build array of cards
foreach ($cards as $card){
    foreach ($suits as $suit){
        $deck[] = $card . " of " . $suit;
    }
}

// shuffle deck - see what I did there? ;)
shuffle($deck);

// add shuffled cards to another array while removing the aces
foreach($deck as $card){
    $pos = strrpos(strtolower($card), "ace");
    if ($pos === false) {
        // not an ace, add to array
        $no_aces[] = $card;
    }
}

// $no_aces array now contains all the shuffled cards without the aces
var_dump($no_aces);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just throwing a wild guess out there, but...

```
$n=1;

while(($draw = array_pop($deck)) != NULL) {
    $card = $cards[$draw / 4];

    if (strtolower($card) != 'ace') {
        echo $n.') '.$card . ' of ' . $suits[$draw % 4] . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $n++;
}
```

http://codepad.org/JyDeOR7d

Comment: Something weird going on there, 49 output rows (would expect 48) and one of them shows a result of ' of Clubs'.

Comment: Another odd thing is that the results are always the same. Hey, you want to join a poker game with me and conmen? `:P`